# Como Formatar Cada Tag HTML Com Seus Atributos Em Cores Sortidas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Uma "imagem" diz mais que muitas palavras não é verdade!? Então convido a ver o:

## Exemplo

[image]

> Nesta image vemos algumas "tags" formatado nas cores *"vermelho(red),  marrom(maroon) e azul(skyblue)"*

O que pretendo com isso é fazer o que um programa/software editor HTML ja faz. Isto é, todo o processo que destaca as tags.

Veja um código de *exemplo logo abaixo* feito manualmente:

## Código

```js
function Tag()
{
// Faz alguma coisa para setar as cores

...

// Fim de rotina cores sortidas
}
Tag();
```

```css
div.code 
{ 
border: thin solid silver; 
width:720px; 
height:390px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="code">

<pre>

01 - &lt;!DOCTYPE html>
02 -
03 - &lt;html lang="en">
04 - &lt;head>
05 -  &lt;meta charset="utf-8"/>
06 -  &lt;title>Centralizar DIV&lt;/title>
07 -  &lt;link href="centralizar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
08 - &lt;/head>
09 - &lt;body>
10 -
11 -  &lt;div id="site">
12 -
13 -   &lt;h1>Edu??o superior na regi??o de camplinas&lt;/h1>
14 -
15 -   &lt;p>Resultado do Censo 2010 mostra o percentual da popula??o
16 -     das cidades da regi?o de Camplinas com forma??o superior.
17 -     Compara??o com a m?dia do estado de SP e nacional&lt;/p>
18 -
19 -   &lt;img src="grafico.jpg" alt="Gr?fico"/>
20 -
21 -  &lt;/div>
22 -
23 - &lt;/body>
24 -
25 - &lt;/html>

</div>
```

> Sabemos que isso é útil para escrevermos artigos e mostrarmos um trecho do código de maneira destacada e bem apresentada no Site/Blog.

## Lembrete

Não estou buscando modificar cores de texto, mas sim, a cor das tag HTML, é totalmente o inverso ao contrário do conceito de estilizar um elemento com CSS.

## Dúvida

Como farei este efeito, da "image" no "código"?

Comment: Onde quer aplicar essa sua idéia?

Comment: @EmanuelF Como assim!? Note o que diz "[...] é útil para escrevermos artigos e mostrarmos um trecho do código de maneira destacada e bem apresentada no Site/Blog.", compreendeu?

Comment: Agora ficou mais claro, então quer criar um campo em que as tags fiquem destacadas com cores diferentes? Algo que você usou aqui pra exemplificar sua ideia?

Comment: @EmanuelF Isso mesmo, gosto de criar tudo a mão e não faço uso de editores HTML. Então, seria interessante e funcional criar uma rotina externa para pré formatar pequenos trecho dentro de uma DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome deste tipo de pós-processamento é *code mark-up*, ou *marcação de código*.

Existem várias bibliotecas disponíveis para realizar este tipo de marcação para você.

Uma das mais utilizadas chama-se [hljs (highlight.js)](https://highlightjs.org/).

Clique em <kbd>Executar trecho de código</kbd> para ver o exemplo em javascript a seguir:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.5.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.5.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.5.0/languages/javascript.min.js"></script>

<pre><code class="javascript">
app.factory("callbackFactory", function ($log) {

        function registerCallBack(factoryInstance, collection, callback) {
            collection.push(callback);

            //$log.log(factoryInstance.moduleName + " observers: " + collection.length);

            if (factoryInstance.onSubscriberRegistrationCallback)
                factoryInstance.onSubscriberRegistrationCallback(callback);
        };
    };
</code></pre>
```